# Algorithm - Partition two numbers about a power-of-two

Tags: algorithm

Given two floating point numbers, `p` and `q` where `0 < p < q` I am interested in writing a function `partition(p,q)` that finds the 'simplest' number `r` that is between `p` and `q`.  For example:

```
partition(3.0, 4.1) = 4.0 (2^2)
partition(4.2, 7.0) = 6.0 (2^2 + 2^1)
partition(2.0, 4.0) = 3.0 (2^1 + 2^0)
partition(0.3, 0.6) = 0.5 (2^-1)
partition(1.0, 10.0) = 8.0 (2^3)
```

In the last instance I am interested in the largest number (so 8 as opposed to 4 or 2).

Comment: What's the simplest number definition?

Comment: Isn't this simply resolved via one or more of `{truncation(), ceiling(), floor()}` operations on the binary representation?

Comment: Yes, a straightforward manipulation on the binary representation should be enough implement this.

Comment: It's not very clear, but you want a number `r` where the mantissa has the lowest possible popcnt it can get while still being between `p` and `q`, right?

Comment: @harold I think that the criterion is not the popcount of the mantissa but the number of trailing zeroes.

Comment: @Freddie: FYI, John H. Conway has used the same term ("simplest") for defining a similar notion about surreal numbers. You coincide when the number is a fraction but his simplest for `(1,10)` is `2`, not `8`. See **Surreal Numbers**: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number

Comment: Link for 2 famous related books: **ONAG (by Conway)**: http://downloads.akpeters.com/product.asp?ProdCode=1276 and **Surreal numbers (by Knuth)**: http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/sn.html

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the term 'simplest', I really was not sure how to precisely define what I required.  (And would be very interested if there is a proper definition!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume assume that `p` and `q` are both normalized and positive, and `p < q`.

If `p` and `q` have differing exponents, it appears that the number you are looking for is the number obtained by zeroing the mantissa of `q` after the leading (and often implicit) 1. The corner cases are left as an exercise, especially the case where `q`'s mantissa is already made of zeroes after the leading, possibly implicit, `1`.

If `p` and `q` have the same exponent, then we have to look at their mantissas. These mantissas have some bits in common (starting from the most significant end). Let us call `c1 c2 .. ck pk+1 ... pn` the bits of `p`'s mantissa, `c1 c2 .. ck qk+1 ... qn`the bits of `q`'s mantissa, where `c1 .. ck` are common bits and `pk+1`, `qk+1` differ. Then `pk+1` is zero and `qk+1` is one (because of the hypotheses). The number with the same exponent and mantissa `c1 .. ck 1 0 .. 0` is in the interval `p .. q` and is the number you are looking for (again, corner cases left as an exercise).

Comment: 'zeroing the mantissa': to be clear, this assumes IEEE 754 (or something very similar), and in particular that the bits being set to zero don't include the implicit hidden '1' bit, right?

Comment: @Mark Dickinson Yes, I was using the verb "zeroing" thinking of the IEEE 754 representation with implicit leading `1`. I said I was assuming `q` to be normalized, though, so if we are not using IEEE 754, the idea stands, just do not zero the leading `1`.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Perhaps you could make it clearer that your use of 'mantissa' in this context doesn't include the leading 1.  (After all, in some floating-point formats, like the outdated IEEE 754-1985 80-bit extended precision format, that 1 *is* included explicitly in the bit representation of the number.)

Answer (score 1):

- Write the numbers in binary (terminating if possible, so 1 is written as `1.0000...`, not `0.1111...`),
- Scan from left to right, "keeping" all digits at which the two numbers are equal
- At the first digit where the two numbers differ, `p` must be 0 and `q` must be 1 since `p < q`:

  - If `q` has any more 1 digits after this point, then put a 1 at this point and you're done.
  - If `q` has no more 1 digits after this point, then doing that would result in `r == q`, which is forbidden, so instead append a 0 digit. Follow that by a 1 digit unless doing so would result in `r == p`, in which case append another 0 and then a 1.

Basically, we truncate `q` down to the first place at which `p` and `q` differ, then jigger it a bit if necessary to avoid `r == p` or `r == q`. The result is certainly less than `q` and greater than `p`. It is "simplest" (has the least possible number of 1 digits) since any number between `p` and `q` must share their common initial sequence. We have added only one 1 digit to that sequence, which is necessary since the initial sequence alone is `<= p`, so no value in range `(p,q)` has fewer 1 digits. We've chosen the "largest" solution because we always place our extra 1 at the first (biggest) possible place.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to convert the binary representation of the largest integer strictly less than your largest argument to the corresponding sum of powers of two.

Comment: This feels like more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: It is both a comment and an answer. But the more I read the original question, the more I realize it makes no sense.

Comment: but what's the solution of Partition(2.7, 2.8) then? 2.75? 2.79? e?